Unreal Engine 5 зависает редактор каждую секунду
При запуске игры в редакторе Unreal Engine весь редактор начинает зависать каждую секунду, при этом степень загруженности процессора и видеокарты минимальная. Драйвера обновлял ничего не менялось. Зависает именно редактор Unreal, рабочий стол или другие приложения работают исправно. Windows 10 22H2

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Мы заметили, что ваш вопрос требует некоторых уточнений. Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как правильно задавать вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
